# NLog.Config только для чтения

Tags: c#, config, nlog, логирование, readonly

Пытаюсь подключить логгер, скачал пакет NLog и NLog.Config. По гайду нужно внести изменения в NLog.Config, но сделать я это не могу так-как он readonly. Как это можно отключить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В файл проекта запихните да и все (`app.config`) или как то так.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ как только установил NLog.config он автоматически запихнулся в проект. Можно подробнее пожалуйста, а то я не совсем понимаю

Comment: Можно просто снят галку только для чтения

Comment: @Vasek, ну если можно было просто снять галку только для чтения, то я не спрашивал бы. По крайней мере я ее нигде не нашел. Может есть идеи где поискать?

Comment: @Denis Ну, то что он генерирует, это наверно хорошо, но смысл носить с собой 2 файла конфига (приложения и лога)? Я обычно это все помещаю в один. В папке с проектом найдите `App.config`, в нем будет простой xml, в котором будет секция `configuration`, вот внутрь этой секции перенесите все из сгенерированного файла (кроме заголовка) и будет вам счастье. Если файла `App.config` нету, то ПКМ - добавить - файл конфигурации (или как то так). Вообще я вам кстати советую попробовать `Serilog`, он более удобный и современный для логов.

Comment: Я про обычную [галгу](https://support.content.office.net/en-us/media/5c1605ad-47cb-4539-a10f-c706abf48f1c.png) файловой системы

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, спасибо за развернутый ответ. Последую вашему совету и попробую Serilog

Comment: @Vasek, глянул в файловой системе, она там по дефолту снята была. Видимо от этого не зависит. За идею спасибо!